# How can get value of "FileSystemWatcher" in other loop function

Tags: c#, delegates

I have class "SystemWatchFile" used to detect a file change . Every a file changed so i can capture this change in function "OnChanged".
In other loop function i call to SystemWatchFile to monitor the change of file. Like below :

```
       while (true)
        {
            SystemWatchFile watchfile = new SystemWatchFile(@" f:\Tutorial\C#\FileSytemWatcher\readme.txt");
            watchfile.Run();

            ///at here , how can i get value from "OnChanged" , when a file is changed
        }
```

I try use to delegate to implement callback  but not work.My class :

```
public class SystemWatchFile
{
    string FileNeedWatching = "";
    bool let = false;
    public SystemWatchFile(string file)
    {
        FileNeedWatching = file;
    }
    public  void Run()
    {
        using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher())
        {
            string filePath1 = FileNeedWatching;
            watcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath1);
            // Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
            // the renaming of files or directories.
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                                 | NotifyFilters.FileName
                                 | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

            // Only watch text files.
            watcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName(filePath1);
            // Add event handlers.
            watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
            // Begin watching.
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        }

    }
    private  void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (let == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"File: {e.FullPath} {e.ChangeType}");
            let = true;
        }
        else
        {
            let = false;
        }            

    }
}
```

How can i get value when file change ?

Comment: you `Dispose` the `watcher` just after creation: `using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher()) {...}`

Comment: not understood can you elaborate.